# Finding the keys of extra rows which got added, after a left join on two data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes(say dataframe A and dataframe B) and I merged them with pandas merge functionality.

```
merged = A.merge(B, left_on = ["A_Key1", "A_Key2"], right_on = ["B_Key1", "B_Key2"], how = 'left')
```

Due to some dupliacte rows in Table B, the merged result came out with some extra rows than that of table A.

I just want to find out the what are the values of "A_Key1" of those extra rows.

I have tried below things:

```
dup = A.loc[B.duplicated(["B_Key1", "B_Key2"]),:]

dup['B_Key1'].isin(A["A_Key1", "B_Key2"].unique())
```

But this is not working, as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) only for `A` `DataFrame`:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
        'A_Key1':[3,3,6,5,5,4],
        'A_Key2':list('aaabbb')
})

B = pd.DataFrame({
        'B':list('qwerty'),
        'B_Key1':[5,3,6,1,3,5],
        'B_Key2':list('aaaaab')
})

merged = A.merge(B, left_on=["A_Key1", "A_Key2"], right_on=["B_Key1", "B_Key2"], how = 'left')
print (merged)
   A  A_Key1 A_Key2    B  B_Key1 B_Key2
0  a       3      a    w     3.0      a
1  a       3      a    t     3.0      a
2  b       3      a    w     3.0      a
3  b       3      a    t     3.0      a
4  c       6      a    e     6.0      a
5  d       5      b    y     5.0      b
6  e       5      b    y     5.0      b
7  f       4      b  NaN     NaN    NaN
```

---

```
dup = merged[merged.duplicated(["B_Key1", "B_Key2"])]
print (dup)
   A  A_Key1 A_Key2  B  B_Key1 B_Key2
1  a       3      a  t     3.0      a
2  b       3      a  w     3.0      a
3  b       3      a  t     3.0      a
6  e       5      b  y     5.0      b

dup1 = merged.loc[merged.duplicated(["A_Key1", "A_Key2"]), 
                 ['A_Key1','A_Key2','B_Key1','B_Key2']]
print (dup1)
   A_Key1 A_Key2  B_Key1 B_Key2
1       3      a     3.0      a
2       3      a     3.0      a
3       3      a     3.0      a
6       5      b     5.0      b
```

Comment: @jazrael I think that would work, tried that too before. But the result is coming out to be larger, than the additional rows that were added.

Comment: @HarishJ - hmmm, what about test values from output? Answer was edited.